# ERROR DseModule.java:114 - Class not found: org/apache/lucene/uninverting/FieldCache. Exiting

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

My cassandra was working and suddenly I get the error
with 6.8 and I am using java 8

`ERROR [main] 2022-03-19 21:27:23,812  DseModule.java:114 - Class not found: org/apache/lucene/uninverting/FieldCache. Exiting...`

**My java version**

java -version java version "1.8.0_181" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

**I am running the command,**
`bin/dse cassandra`
to start cassandra

I have tried removing cassandra and reinstalling. I even tried deleting the /var/lib/cassandra folder

Answer (score 0):

The error on its own doesn't give us an indication of the problem. We need quite a bit more information including:

- log files
- `cassandra.yaml` and `dse.yaml`
- OS platform and version

My suggestion is that you should log a ticket with [DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com) so one of our engineers can assist you. Cheers!